# woocommerce - pass the product if into custom function while adding an action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add an action for the woocommerce hook `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` and here I am trying to get the product id in the custom function I am using to hook. For this I have used `get_the_ID()` inside the function but it is not working. Is there any way to pass the woocommerce product id into my custom function while doing `add_action`?

**My Code:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'order_session_date');

function order_session_date() {
   global $woocommerce;
   $product_id = get_the_ID();
   $sched_val = get_post_meta($product_id, '_sched_val', true);
   $data = array(
       $data_dates = $sched_val
   );
   WC()->session->set('name_for_your_data', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its a filter, the second parameter is the the id, make sure you return the first argument.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'order_session_date', 10, 2);

function order_session_date( $data, $id) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $product_id = $id;
   $sched_val = get_post_meta($product_id, '_sched_val', true);
   $data = array(
       $data_dates = $sched_val
   );
   WC()->session->set('name_for_your_data', $data);

   return $data;
}
```

Comment: For the OP, the [`woocommerce_add_to_cart_item_data`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/c6dfe47ffabbd4cf7eb981a4c3c7b7504c824d6c/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L911) filter in the source.